# Making Twisted Python simple client server example to work

Tags: python, twisted

I am new to Twisted python (Twisted 12.x, python 2.6.x, unfortunately I have to use the older version), and I am running client/server in which the server echoes a simple message from the client (example from chap 2 of Twisted O'reilly book) I am running server in a terminal, and then client in a separate terminal. But client and server are stuck (not returning). What is failing?

server:

```
from twisted.internet import protocol, reactor

class Echo(protocol.Protocol): 
    def dataReceived(self, data):
        self.transport.write(data)

class EchoFactory(protocol.Factory): 
    def buildProtocol(self, addr):
        return Echo() 

reactor.listenTCP(50000, EchoFactory())
reactor.run()
```

client:

```
from twisted.internet import reactor, protocol

class EchoClient(protocol.Protocol): 
    def connectionMade(self):
        self.transport.write("Hello, world!")

def dataReceived(self, data):
    print "Server said:", data 
    self.transport.loseConnection()

class EchoFactory(protocol.ClientFactory): 
    def buildProtocol(self, addr):
        return EchoClient()

def clientConnectionFailed(self, connector, reason): 
    print "Connection failed."
    reactor.stop()

def clientConnectionLost(self, connector, reason): 
    print "Connection lost."
    reactor.stop()

reactor.connectTCP("localhost", 50000, EchoFactory())
reactor.run()
```

Comment: In your ``client.py`` indent the entire ``dataReceived``, ``clientConnectionFailed``, ``clientConnectionLost`` and you should go okay

Answer (score 0):

Your `dataReceived`, `clientConnectionFailed`, and `clientConnectionLost` methods are not indented, which means they are just free functions that are never being called, rather than overriding methods on `Protocol` or `ClientFactory`.  So your client code will get the default `dataReceived` implementation, which is "do nothing".

Also, by the way, Python 2.6 is out of security support and will not receive updates.  Please upgrade to version 2.7.9 at least.  You should also upgrade to a recent version of Twisted, especially if this is for new code; there is really no legitimate reason to use software this old; it is dangerous and irresponsible to do so.